# Using awk to parse a config file

Tags: bash, awk, subshell

I'm trying to make an `awk` command which stores an entire config file as variables.

The config file is in the following form (keys never have spaces, but values may):

```
key=value
key2=value two
```

And my awk command is:

```
$(awk -F= '{printf "declare %s=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2}' $file)
```

Running this without the outer subshell `$(...)` results in the exact commands that I want being printed, so my question is less about awk, and more about how I can run the output of awk as commands.

The command evaluates to:

```
declare 'key="value"'
```

which is somewhat of a problem, since then the double quotes are stored with the value. Even worse is when a space is introduced, which results in:

```
declare 'key2="value' two"
```

Of course, I cannot remove the quotes or the multi-word values cause problems.

I've tried most every solution I could find, such as `set -f`, `eval`, and `system()`.

Comment: If I do `eval $(echo k=value two | awk -F= '{printf "declare %s=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2}')` and then `echo $k` it returns me `value two`. Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `Awk` for this but the do this with built-ins available. Read the config file properly using input redirection

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS== read -r k v; do
    declare "$k"="$v"
done < config_file
```

and source the file as

```
$ source script.sh
$ echo "$key"
value
$ echo "$key2"
value two
```

If `source` is not available explicitly, `POSIX`-ly way of doing it would be to do just

```
. ./script.sh
```

Comment: The source command was actually exactly what I needed. I ended up doing: `source <(awk .....)`, but I respect that your answer is superior for not using unnecessary tools.